# PHP arithmetic for getting average

Tags: php, math, foreach, average

I'm trying to practice PHP and I encountered this problem, this is just a simple calculation to get the average but is seems that when I input the numbers they giving me the wrong answer.

```
<?php 

if(!empty($_POST['first'])&&$_POST['second']&&$_POST['third']&&$_POST['fourth']&&$_POST['fifth'])
  {

$first = $_POST['first'];
$second = $_POST['second'];
$third = $_POST['third'];
$fourth = $_POST['fourth'];
$fifth = $_POST['fifth'];
$average = array($first,$second,$third,$fourth,$fifth);
$total = 0;

foreach($average as $value){
    $total =+ $value;
}
 $the_average = $total/count($average);
    echo $the_average;


}else{
echo 'Please complete all fields';
 }

?>

 <html>
<head><title>Test run</title></head>
<body>

<form method="POST">
    Quizzes
    <input type='text' name="first" maxlength="2"> ,
    <input type='text' name="second" maxlength="2"> ,
    <input type='text' name="third" maxlength="2"> ,
    <input type='text' name="fourth" maxlength="2"> ,
    <input type='text' name="fifth" maxlength="2"> ,
    <input type="submit" value="submit" >

</form>
```

Comment: It's `+=` not `=+`

Comment: Just thought I'd mention that `empty('0') === true`, yet zero is a valid number.  You can validate input with an is_numeric check.

Comment: i still get the wrong answer

Comment: `$the_average = array_sum($average) / count($average);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 

if(!empty($_REQUEST['first']) && $_REQUEST['second'] && $_REQUEST['third'] && $_REQUEST['fourth'] && $_REQUEST['fifth'])
  {

$first = $_REQUEST['first'];
$second = $_REQUEST['second'];
$third = $_REQUEST['third'];
$fourth = $_REQUEST['fourth'];
$fifth = $_REQUEST['fifth'];
$average = array($first,$second,$third,$fourth,$fifth);
$total = array_sum($average);

$the_average = $total/count($average);
echo $the_average;
}else{
echo 'Please complete all fields';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

we suppose that $first to $fifth may be `string`, so let's try to make it `flot`.

```
<?php
    $first = $_POST['first'];
    $second = $_POST['second'];
    $third = $_POST['third'];
    $fourth = $_POST['fourth'];
    $fifth = $_POST['fifth'];
    $average = array($first,$second,$third,$fourth,$fifth);
    $total = floatval(0);

    foreach($average as $value){
        $total =+ floatval($value);
    }
    $the_average = floatval($total)/count($average);
    echo number_format(floatval($the_average),2, '.', '');
?>
```